# Connect shapes using an arrow in d3

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I'm trying to connect 3 basic customs shapes using arrows, I took this [arrow](http://jsfiddle.net/yeQS2/89/) as reference.

I'd like to replicate the behavior of [lucidchart](https://www.lucidchart.com/demo) for moving any shape, I've seen a lot of examples using the force layout, but I'm not sure if that is good candidate for what I'm trying to achieve, so any guidance will be appreciated.

this is my code:

```
var data =[{"x":"100.0","y":"100.0","name":"shape-0","id":"543fe9949382ed4a16c38cf3","type":"startEvent","index":0},{"x":"610","y":"100.0","name":"shape-1","id":"543fe9949382ed4a16c38cf5","type":"endEvent","index":1},{"x":"318","y":"93","name":"first task","id":"543fe9a09382ed4a16c38cf6","type":"task","index":2}];

var links = [
    {"source":{"x":136,"y":118},
     "target":{"x":318,"y":118}},
    {"source":{"x":428,"y":118},
     "target":{"x":610,"y":118}}];

var node = svg.selectAll('g').data(data)
    .enter()
    .append(function(d){
        return shapes[d.type](d).node();
    });

var link = svg.selectAll('.link')
.data(links).enter().append('g').attr('class', 'node')
.append('line')
.attr('class','path')
.style('stroke-width', 2)
.attr('marker-end', 'url(#arrow)');

link.selectAll("line").attr("x1", function(d){
      return d.source.x;
    }).attr("y1", function(d){
      return d.source.y;
    }).attr("x2", function(d){
      return d.target.x;
    }).attr("y2", function(d){
      return d.target.y;
    })

//arrows
svg.append('svg:defs').append('svg:marker')
.attr('id', 'arrow').attr('viewBox', '0 0 10 10')
.attr('refX', 0).attr('refY', 5)
.attr('markerUnits', 'strokeWidth')
.attr('markerWidth', 8)
.attr('markerHeight', 6)
.attr('orient', 'auto')
.append('svg:path')
.attr('d', 'M 0 0 L 10 5 L 0 10 z');


svg.append('line')
.attr('x1', 5)
.attr('x2', 50)
.attr('y1', 5)
.attr('y2', 50)
.style('stroke', 'black')
.attr('stroke-width', 2)
.attr('marker-end', 'url(#arrow)');
```

**This is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pedromullerrw/vwq0z5nk/9/) for reference.**
thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of layout are you trying to create? A force directed graph? It doesn't look like you've tried to use a layout. I don't see any "d3.layout.[something]" anywhere. If you compare the two fiddles you've provided, that's the biggest difference.

Comment: Looking at how Lucidcharts does it, I believe you would want a tree layout with simple draggable nodes. The curvy lines made me think of one of my projects: http://jsfiddle.net/mctalian/rx27oLgn/

You would have to restructure your data, or have a function that changes it from "flat" to "interleaved" (I can provide links to what I've found, that's one of my next steps). But after that it should be pretty easy to do what you want to do.

Comment: I haven't implemented a layout yet, I'd like some guidance in terms of as you said which layout could be a good fit, if there's no candidate how to implement such behavior using d3

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vwq0z5nk/10/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand the question, I don't think you need a layout at all. Not if you're going for the lucid chart drag functionality.

You have your `data` array, which is your representation of all the shapes in the scene (a.k.a the model), including their x and y position. The goal should be to update those x and y props when a shape is dragged and then re-render all the shapes (via the usual enter, update, exit routine).

The concept of layout would become necessary if there is not an explicit x and y for each shape (like in the case of tree or partition layout) or perhaps if the x and y of each shape are supposed to be transformed into a different x and y (like in the case of force layout).

To implement dragging, you can use [`d3.behavior.drag()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Drag-Behavior#drag), like in [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/6123708). But unlike that example, you would want to modify  the x and y property values of `d`, which is the shape's definition within `data` — not the DOM element's position as the example does.

Comment: @jack.the.ripper [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vwq0z5nk/10/) of what I described. I had to change a bunch of stuff in order to prevent it appending new shapes every time `update()` is called. Also, links' `source` and `target` are now shape objects, so that moving the shape also moves the link.

Comment: I'm new to d3 to I'll take a deeper look to the code and try to understand a little bit more, thanks! that's definitely a quite nice approach!

Comment: @jack.the.ripper cool. The main points: the way you have `data` set up is good as is. The way `links` is set up needs to be in terms of the elements of `data` (as I did in the fiddle). The way you have `shapes` set up could use a refactoring and simplification. Basically, each shape should be a function that takes as param a `g` wrapped in a d3 selection. The `update()` method would call the shape function, which would be responsible for rendering the shape but not positioning it. The positioning can be done inside the `update()` method.

Comment: The shape function should position the `g`'s children (circle or rect and text) relative to the `g` (so the circle's `cx` and `cy` would be 0,0). The translation of that `g`, handled by `update` is what moves the nodes to the appropriate position indicated by `data`.

Comment: thanks for the explanation and for the code +1 for that, I'm just wondering why you should do a shape select, then enter with append and finally do any attribute modification and why it doesn't work to chain all at once

Comment: @jack.the.ripper sorry, I don't fully understand the question. If you can provide a fiddle or a gist that has questions as inline comments about what's not clear, I'll be happy to take a look.

Comment: I'm just wondering why not to do a single var defition and chain all the methods at once like this:  var circle = g.selectAll('circle').data([data]).enter().append('circle').attr('cx', cx).attr('cy', cy).attr('r',  radius+2).attr('class','outerCircle'); I tried it and it doesn't work

Comment: @jack.the.ripper Because that only affects the shapes that enter. Each time you drag-move a shape it calls that function again, but since it's binding to a 1-element array `[data]` and there is already a circle DOM element created, enter() is blank and nothing will update cx and cy. Also, I recommend you move this positioning code out of the functions that render these shapes. Instead, position the container g's in the update function and then just render the shape relative to g's origin. Here's a much cleaner version that demonstrates better: http://jsfiddle.net/pzkcbrtr/1/.